# Sum of Products if label is found in a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to add together the products of all numbers whose labels appear in a list.  For example, in the picture provided, we want the sum of the products of the numbers whose labels are a, e, c, or z.  This would be 1*2+5*6+3*4=44.

[image]

I thought the formula in the picture would work because we would be taking the sum of the products of the first number and either the second number if the label is in the list, or zero otherwise, but I 'm not really sure why this doesn't work.

Comment: Enter the formula with Ctrl + Shift + Enter so the if countif is properly evaluated.

Comment: ... That is the solution.  If you wanna post as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Have posted then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enter the formula with Ctrl + Shift + Enter so the if countif is properly evaluated. That way you have two arrays of equal length for SUMPRODUCT.